# TFS 2017 TestExecution.zip inaccessible to test agent machine

Tags: automated-tests

I'm very confused by the behavior of the TFS 2017u2 Deploy Test Agent task when operating in offline mode. The task appears to fail when looking on the test agent machine for a path local to the deployment agent. Either that or it fails trying to connect via admin share.

Using the Deploy Test Agent task in Release Management, the Test Agent will install successfully from a separate UNC share. However, the task will then detect the DTAAgentExecutionService and DTAExecutionHost are not present/running. It looks like the RemoteDeployerService then reaches back from the Test Agent workstation to the Deployment Agent machine to grab a copy of the TestExecution.zip archive. This elicits warnings in the log: "Failed to connect to the path \\******** with the user....", "System error 53 has occurred," and "The network path was not found." Finally, the effort fails with:

### [error]Error occured on '********:5986'. Details : 'Test agent source path 'D:\agents\DA_1\_work\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\2.1.8\TestExecution.zip' is not accessible to the test machine. Please check if the file exists and that test machine has access to that machine'.

That path is clearly referencing the deployment agent machine, however, so I don't know why the test agent would be looking for it in a local path (d:\ instead of \\). To be sure, I manually logged into the test agent workstation with the same account configured for the RM task and I can access that folder and archive remotely via \\d$\ share without a problem.

Is the test agent trying to reach back to the deployment agent?

I expected the deployment agent machine to initiate the installation and monitor remotely, pushing content to the test agent workstation as required. In our production space firewalls allow traffic originating from the deployment agent to reach the test agent but not the other way around.

If not, what is it doing? Where does it expect to find TestExecution.zip? I tried putting a copy in the same UNC folder as the TestAgent.zip installer but that did nothing.

Comment: According to the error log, the test agent is trying to remote back to deployment agent machine and fetch the file TestExecution.zip locally in the deployment agent.  Not the way you thought to direclty copy files to test agent machine workstation. Suggest you compare logs with an environment which allow both  deployment agent to reach the test agent   and the other way around.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickLu-MSFT. After some additional tracing it appears the machines will need bidirectional WinRM and UNC traffic both. I'm not sure why this wasn't built to just use WinRM exclusively for the file copying and management but hopefully this will be streamlined at some point.